# Using joda time in play Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime

I wrote the next Scala function:

```
def compareBeforeDateTimes(d1: String, d2: String)
{
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    DateTime dt1 = formatter.parseDateTime(d1)
    DateTime dt2 = formatter.parseDateTime(d2)
    return dt1 < dt2
}
```

At the beginning of my Scala code I wrote:

```
import org.joda.time.{Period, DateTime}
import org.joda.time.format.{DateTimeFormat}
import org.joda.time.format.{DateTimeFormatter}
```

Yet, if I compile my code I get the error:

```
value formatter is not a member of object org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am down voting because the extremely basic Scala constructs of declaring variables are wrong. The question can be modified with the right construct or changing the context to the suitable language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how variables are declared in Scala.

It should be

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Note that you can leave the type declaration off, as it is inferred. If you really wanted to also declare the type, it would be

```
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

This is the same syntax as in the function parameters (they are correct there already).

Comment: Also note that with Java 8, JodaTime is mostly obsolete now.

Comment: Man, since Scala does not have a daytime native stuff it gets confusing. I tried to follow other post from StackOverflow about datetime for scala and there is no much stuff about it. Thanks